# Fragment becomes blank after asking for runtime permission

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter, runtime-permissions

I am working on viewPager with fragment and it was working all things perfect before I have start implementing runtime permission for different module.

Here is my viewPager Adapter.

```
public class DashboardAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


  public DashboardAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
     super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {

      switch (position) {
         case 0:
             return FunkyInboxFragment.newInstance(position);
         case 1:
             return FunkyTakePhotoFragment.newInstance(position);
         case 2:
             return FunkyAddFriendsFragmnet.newInstance(position);
         default:
             return FunkyTakePhotoFragment.newInstance(position);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
     return 3;
  }

  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
     Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container,   position);
      return fragment;
  }


  @Override
  public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
  }

}
```

Here different fragments required different permissions so I have made a common activity class for it. It's working in the same fragment but after asking for a permission when I swipe the viewPager the fragment after next fragment and a fragment before previous fragment get blank. i have made all possible change in adapter but did not get a proper outcome.

Please can anyone help with it!

Comment: Please past the code where you have given permission.

Comment: And any fragment code as well.

Comment: In below comments I have mentioned the code. Please look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
return 2;
}
```

//try this may be it work

Comment: I need 3 fragments. that's why I put a getCount() - returns 3;

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.madhavgor.actionbardemolast;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher_bluetooth
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new SecondFragment(), "BLUETOOTH");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThirdFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

//refer this code ....may be it will help you..

Comment: Thanks Madhav but as per adpter i think its some same as like yours as I have used FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead.